# How to track external (js added) HTML in GTM

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, gtmetrix

I would like to ask, are there any solutions to track HTML added after DOM is loaded? There is a JS script which adds piece of HTML I cannot track by default rule in GTM. Basically "Link click" & "Any element click" is not working.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Please share the relevant code, that creates the element, and also your relevant tag settings. This scenario should be supported by GTM by default.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot show the js which is injecting the HTML. Here is how tag is configured in GTM as well as screen from the tag preview. 
https://ibb.co/wwCYGqK
https://ibb.co/nf7zC34
https://ibb.co/ByZ1v7T

I really appreciate your support, unfortunately I have no idea what to change

Comment: That's probably has little to do with added HTML. If an element is accessible in the moment of click than the CSS condition will work. Consider checking your selector

Comment: I have found that configured rule was wrong, I have make it correct (green checked on the preview), but tag is still not triggered :(
https://ibb.co/x53qdfH

Comment: I have solved the problem :) Instead of using "Any element click" i choose "Link click" and improve the setting I configured before. Thank you very much for your help :)